# Routing traffic through PPTP VPN

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, pptp

I have a Windows XP SP3 with set up VPN PPTP server, and i need to make it available for the clients to access the internet via the VPN server, but i have a problem.

Everything is set up corectly (I think), but the users are not able to browse web sites. 
I was suspicious in the dns servers, so i did nslookup about severall sites and it worked without any problems. I tried to ping google, but it didn't work - the ping succesfully resolved the ip of google.com but it showed request timed out on every packet. I tried to ping the vpn server and it seemed ok. 
I don't know where the problem could be - The "use default gateway" option on the clients is selected too. 
I really have no idea what the problem could be. Some friend mentioned about internet connection sharing, but i couldn't understand him.

If anyone here can help me even a little, please do, i really need help now.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what's happening is that clients can access the VPN server itself, but can't use it as a gateway.

You will need to create/enable a NAT interface in RRAS so that the VPN server can act as a NAT gateway/router to the internet.